# Pupperserver with Adopt-OpenJDK

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise, puppetlabs-apache, rspec-puppet

We are in transition from Puppetmaster 3.8 to Puppet server(OpenSource) 5.3. 
As a prerequisite for Puppetserver 5.3 installation requires Java 8 runtime packages. Can we install Adopt-OpenJDK with Pupperserver 5.3?

Answer (score 1):

Puppetserver runs just fine on OpenJDK, but I strongly recommend that you run the server on an officially-supported platform (RHEL, CentOS, Debian, Ubuntu, or SLES), and use one of [Puppet, Inc.'s official packages](https://puppet.com/docs/puppetserver/5.3/install_from_packages.html) for that system.  These each express a dependency on an appropriate Java 8 package, and they will configure Puppet properly to work in conjunction with that implementation.  On the platforms for which I have knowledge of the details, it is the distro's OpenJDK build that is used.

It should be possible to [re]configure Puppetserver to use an Adopt-OpenJDK implementation of the Java 8 runtime, but this is swimming upstream.

Comment: Thanks John.Adding one more point here puppetserver has a dependency on openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64.But adopt open jdk is not providing headless package.So we suspect this may cause issue as puppetserver will look for the headless package

Comment: Yes, @SarathS, as I said, "On the platforms for which I have knowledge of the details, it is the distro's OpenJDK build that is used [as the package dependency]."  My recommendation is to go with this, as opposed to using a different build *of the same software*.  It should not inherently present an issue to have two Java builds installed side by side, but you're making significant extra work for yourself whose purpose and benefit is opaque to me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks John.Adding one more point here puppetserver has a dependency on openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64.But adopt open jdk is not providing headless package.So we suspect this may cause issue as puppetserver will look for the headless package.